# In Angular find an object based on the Id provided in the main object

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have 2 Objects

Product

```
_id
productName
taxId
```

Tax

```
_id
taxName
taxRate
```

Using Angular I want to be able to use the `taxId` in `Product` and find the corresponding `taxName` and `taxRate` and result the final object like this.

```
_id
productName
taxId
taxName
taxRate
```

I suppose the tax fields could be nested if needed.

EDIT: Adding the code as requested reducing unnecessary parts.

product.ts

```js
export interface Product {
  _id: string
  productName: string
  taxId: string
}
```

tax.ts

```js
export interface Tax {
  _id: string
  taxName: string
  igstRate: number
  cgstRate: number
  sgstRate: number
}
```

the service.

```js
export class TaxService {
  private productUrl = Url + 'products';
  private taxUrl = Url + 'taxs';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAllPdt(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(this.productUrl);
  }

  getAllTax(): Observable<Tax[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Tax[]>(this.taxUrl);
  }

  getOneTax(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.taxUrl + '/find/' + id);
  }
}
```

the component is Updated as @SomeStudent answer

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaxService } from '../services/tax.service';
import { Tax } from '../interfaces/tax';
import { Product } from '../interfaces/product';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tax',
  templateUrl: './tax.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tax.component.css'],
})
export class TaxComponent implements OnInit {
  taxs: Tax[] = [];
  products: Product[] = [];

  combinedItems : any[] = [];

  constructor(public taxService: TaxService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    combineLatest([
      this.taxService.getAllPdt(),
      this.taxService.getAllTax(),
    ]).subscribe(([pdts, taxes]: [Product[], Tax[]]) => {

      if (taxes && pdts) {
        this.products = pdts;
        this.taxs = taxes;

        this.combinedItems = this.products
          .map((x) => {
            let productProperties = ({
              _id: x._id,
              productName: x.productName,
              taxId: x.taxId,
            } = x);

            let taxItem = taxes.find((z) => z._id == x.taxId);
            if (taxItem) {
              let taxProperties = ({
                taxName: taxItem.taxName,
                igstRate: taxItem.igstRate,
                cgstRate: taxItem.cgstRate,
                sgstRate: taxItem.sgstRate,
              } = taxItem);
              let item = { ...productProperties, ...taxProperties };
              console.log(item);
              return item
            }

            return null;
          })
          .filter((x) => x !== null);
      }
console.log(this.combinedItems)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here. Better show some actual code. I assume you have arrays of these objects and like to create a new array with combined objects?

Comment: I posted a small answer with what I can only assume is what you want to achieve, that said it is hard to figure out exactly what you need as MikeOne said. Not enough code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, this is not related to angular, this is a JS/TypeScript question. Angular is a front end framework. Below is some very rough, big picture pseudo-ish code. The biggest part here is the `...` operator. This is called a spread operator. What it does is it "spreads" all of the properties of the object we are working with, we can use it to reduce the amount of syntax we write.

A bit more reading: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-object-destructuring-spread-operator-rest-parameter/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

That said, if you have two separate collections of Product and Tax:

```
myProducts: Product[] = [];
myTaxes: Tax[] = [];

//populate your products and tax arrays however you do
```

Then what you can do is:

```
let myProduct = this.myProducts.find(x => x._id == productId);
let myTaxForProduct = this.myTaxes.find(x => x._id == myProduct.taxId);

let subPartsOfMyTax =  taxId, taxName, taxRate } = myTaxForProduct;
let mySpecialObject = {
...myProduct, ...subPartsOfMyTax
}
```

You can try the above, or something similar to it, in your browser's console window.
type the following things in this order

- `let myProduct = {id: 1, t: 'b', n: 'c'}`
- `let myTax = {id: 2, tax: 'alot', taxId: 'c'}`
- `let subPartsOfMyTax = {tax, taxId} = myTax`
- `{...myProduct , ...subPartsOfMyTax }`

End result of the above MVP is: `{id: 2, t: 'b', n: 'c', tax: 'alot', taxId: 'c'}` which is generally speaking the same general concept of what you want to achieve.

Edit: Now that you've posted the code.

**Your component.ts file**

```
combinedItems : any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {

    combineLatest([this.taxService.getAllPdt(), 
this.taxService.getAllTax()])
.pipe()
.subscribe(([pdts, taxes] : [Product[], Tax[]) => {
   if(taxes && pdts) {
      this.products = pdts;
      this.taxs = taxes;          

      combinedItems = this.products.map(x => {
    let productProperties = {_id: x._id, productName: x.productName, taxId: x.taxId } = x;
    let taxItem = taxes.find(z => z._id == x.taxId);

    if(taxItem) {
      let taxProperties = { 
            taxName: taxItem.taxName ,
            igstRate: taxItem.igstRate, 
            cgstRate: taxItem.cgstRate, 
            sgstRate: taxItem.sgstRate 
        } = taxItem;

      let item = {...productProperties, ...taxProperties};
      return item;
    }

    return null;}
    }).filter(x => x !== null);
}
```

Working JS Fiddle of just the core logic: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=17&pln=39&pc=44#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwB7IN4FgBQyyA+sACYBcyAzmFKAOYFFiYBycAthFbfSE0LJgDWgCU4kKiACunAEbRmyBKLASpyWQqVDqajTy1zFUAgF8CBUJFiIUABSgB7MjIRgcy0pRp1GygAOLm4eHNy8-gLKrBgAkr58AfiW+AQIziC0yMGu7mDUyFROeR4A2gC6yAC8yJUA3OmZ2bEQhVToGJU1dRWN+ABucFAqzgqgEGRxkJztyHAgAJ7dtQ1W+BlZnoHOgTIANpIQACKScD0AFACUNQB8XkK5oQUAdHvUABYX2D5UAOQAeRAED+ABociF8uEjH9oWDkLEEv9OkCQeYrv0iE98tQ3jJPt9fsg-qgAO7OeHYsJcGHQtDk+GI3wkzBkino-oxTBtPEEn7kZGYVGM9g0wVYOnC8EicRHKgARnBqllmgATOD9CqjABmDlcjA895ffnMzpskUYaHi5B083Sgxy5CKlQOtUa106jnICzrTbZDLjYGoZwMCBgD7QS43ar3PBCIhY3YHI6nVjXTnxhMB+QTKYzQq1KmvThwQIXLAxh4J6vIfZhiGlMAlQLQMDANo9E1UDAvHzgotW5A9gc08FM7svJnIcw9DCYmtEOueREzHqtXEwUBkC4ALzuyB3vfINVqPaZGPWC6IwBgFxXEE4NzjV4TS4RmGbrfbBZw3szL+rWJB3vThJ1FbhkFBZQAJrGV1EdECXjgwxwWgmCsw9KhEOVeDIFQ-90M1XCjEQojDD-dDpzXTBpgfDMYLfYBV1qbAXjYotPygNs2nBNiwIwTjuOocx5xfKAwxkKAQGEGZRJrVI0OrcSwEk6TZH2fY5OrdEXk3fZbHLfcsAAQmqWp1P2C8Ul9ZpPGzCYAEEQDIJwbCjfdn1GQMIGDUNw2gdNlD9Zw6xefYQwuezgTzB9qCshSNjGHNgSclz+DAQL8CAA

Comment: What exactly did you try? Your code only shows you getting data and subscribing to the results. I don't see you actually trying to map the individual elements.

Comment: Updated my code to show how you can create an array of your compound model

Comment: @DasharathSagarNariman I've made some edits, I did write the code without an editor and I guess TS is more strict than JS as in JS using that deconstruction type of syntax is fine. It seems as though you are jsut trying to copy paste the answer without also trying to figure out what is going on as the two errors you mentioned are easy to fix, and the last one can point you to the needed stack overflow.

Comment: I have got this to work the way put in the jsFiddle, but I need to know how to populateData the data from the service instead. Please understand I am pretty much a beginner.

Comment: Well that's a different story then, is your service actually sending a request to a web server? Does it actually successfully get the data if you were to look at your browser's network tab? combineLatest will take data from your service's observables and handle them for you. Once both are returned it will proceed to populate the data

Comment: Service is sending request to server and getting data successfully. No issues no that end. Combine latest was giving me an error when i tried earlier.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: In the subscription, it said `,` was expected. I will give it a try today and see if it is fixable. (I think think a square bracket closing is missing). Also I wonder if there is a better way to declare the properties dynamically as the real products have much of properties and 2 more `taxId` like property to combine. I am also gonna try a different implementation of what I need, maybe when the product is selected, the `taxid` can be send to server to get values of the other properties for that product alone. Btw you have very helpful, thank you for that. I'm deleting my older comments.

Comment: Yep, I think I forgot to close the square bracket. Should be one next to , Tax[]]. Fix that and it should probably work. You can certainly send the tax id to the server and have the server return the exact object type you’re expecting instead of having to create one dynamically. Nevertheless, good learning experience

Comment: I was able to make it work, there were lots of closing curly braces missing as well took me some time to figure out where. I also tried removing the declared properties it seems to work just the same. `let productProperties = x;` `let taxProperties = taxItem;

Comment: Yeah was coding it using the built in slack editor which is pretty bad for formatting. The declared properties was to get specific properties from each object to then assign them. Glad I was able to help/point in the right direction

Comment: I have realised an issue though, I may be able to fix it. Right now with or without declaring the properties all properties of both are being subscribed. Thus the of id of product is no more its, its of tax.

Comment: `let item = {...productProperties, tax: {...taxProperties}};`

Answer (score 0):

see this example:

```
let Product:any[]=[];
Product.push({_id:1,productName:'name1',taxId:101})
Product.push({_id:2,productName:'name2',taxId:102})

let Tax:any[]=[];
Tax.push({_id:1,taxName:'taxName1',taxRate:201})
Tax.push({_id:2,taxName:'taxName2',taxRate:202})


let findtaxID=102; //taxId to be found

let ProductResult=Product.find(x => x.taxId == findtaxID);
let TaxtResult=Tax.find(x => x._id == ProductResult['_id']);

let finalResult={_id:ProductResult['_id'],productName:ProductResult['productName'],taxId:ProductResult['taxId'],
taxName:TaxtResult['taxName'],taxRate:TaxtResult['taxRate']}

console.log(finalResult)
```

and the result:

[image]

Hope this helps!